unexpected value during json deserialization
when using the HtmlResponseMessage.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync function in .NET 8 , sometimes only a false value comes instead of the expected complex value for one of the properties. This causes an exception, and the operation is not performed. How can I ensure that this property is set to null when a different value comes instead of the expected complex value
Thanks in Advance!
var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("", requestArgs, cancellationToken);
result = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<ResponseDto<SomeInfo[]>(cancellationToken);
 
expected json: 
{
  "result": [ { "name" : "a" , "lastname" : "b" } ]
}

unexpected json: 
{
  "result": false
}

public class ResponseDto<T> 
{
    public T Result { get; set; }
}
public class SomeInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}


The BE should never return sometimes a type and sometimes other. Search for polymorphism for ReadFromJsonAsync. If that doesn't cut it, then you can wrap the thing with a try/catch, wich is ugly and considered and anti-pattern or you could try to access the property directly using the keys, and if is boolean type, then do a thing otherwise the other.
